# PDOStatement->bindParam doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have some trouble with `$query->bindParam`. It doesn't change placeholders into values.

`$options` is an array:

```
$options['where'] = [
    'id'    => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    'title' => [ 'some', 'title' ]
];
```

```php
$fields = '*';
$where_clauses = []; /* define empty error which could be filled with where clauses */
/* if it is a separte blog, only posts posted by it's admin should be got */
if ( Main::$current_blog_id !== 1 )
    $where_clauses[] = '`author_id` IN(' . $this->blog->admin_id . ')';

/* if options have been passed */
if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
    /* if there are "where" options */
    if ( ! empty( $options['where'] ) ) {
        $placeholder_number = 1; /* define placeholder number */
        $placeholders       = []; /* create array with placeholders 'placeholder_number' => 'value' */
        foreach ( $options['where'] as $field_name => $values ) {
            $field_values = []; /* values that will be used to create "IN" statement */

            /* fill $fild_values array with values */
            foreach ( $values as $value ) {
                $placeholder = ':' . $placeholder_number; /* create placeholder */

                $field_values[] = $placeholder; /* add placeholder to field values */

                $placeholders[ $placeholder ] = $value; /* add placeholer with it's value to common placeholders array */

                $placeholder_number++; /* increase placeholder number */
            }

            /* turn $fields_values array into string */
            $field_values = implode( ', ', $field_values );

            /* create clause and put it into $where_clauses */
            $where_clauses[] = '`' . $field_name . '` IN(' . $field_values . ')';
        }
    }
}

/* if where statement is empty */
$where_clauses =
    ! empty( $where_clauses ) ?
    implode( ' AND ', $where_clauses ) :
    1;

$query = Main::$data_base->pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT ' . $fields . ' ' .
    'FROM `posts` ' .
    'WHERE ' . $where_clauses . ' ' .
    'LIMIT ' . $posts_quantity . ';'
);

/* if there are placeholders in the query */
if ( ! empty( $placeholders ) ) {
    foreach ( $placeholders as $placeholder => $value )
        $query->bindParam( $placeholder, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR );
}

$query->execute();
$posts = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

var_dump( $query );

return
    ! empty( $posts ) ?
    $posts :
    [];
```

After all of this my printed query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` IN(:1, :2, :3) AND `title` IN(:4, :5) LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: you probably should read some tutorials on how php does arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) **doesn't modify the query string** that you passed to [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). It replaces the placeholders with the value of the variable that you bound to it in the moment you execute the statement and the query is sent to the SQL server.

This should be what you want:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (:1, :2, :3) AND title IN (:4, :5) LIMIT 15;";
$statement = $db->prepare($query); // $db contains the connection to the database
$placeholders = array(':1' => 1, ':2' => 2, ':3' => 3, ':4' => 'some', ':5' => 'title');
foreach ($placeholders as $placeholder => $value) {
  $statement->bindValue($placeholder, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$statement->execute();
```

Note that I use [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and that I modified your SQL query string (`and` instead of `&&`).

You could also do this:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN (:1, :2, :3) AND title IN (:4, :5) LIMIT 15;";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$placeholders = array(':1' => 1, ':2' => 2, ':3' => 3, ':4' => 'some', ':5' => 'title');
$statement->execute($placeholders);
```

Read about `PDOStatement::execute` in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: I had changed the description of the trouble, could u see it?

Comment: What *exactly* does your `var_dump` print? I suppose it's more than just the query string?

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#13 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` IN(:1, :2, :3) AND `title` IN(:4, :5) LIMIT 15;" }

Comment: And that is perfectly correct. With perpared statements, you will never get to see the final query string. I edited my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Facepalm. It`s really works correctly,But  I had seen that placeholders in the query and thought, that something wrong. Thank u and sorry for time thefting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the binds like...

```
 Array ( ':1' => 1, ':2' => 2, ':3' => 3, ':4' => 'some', ':5' => 'title' )
```

Also your select is incorrect...

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN(:1, :2, :3) AND title IN(:4, :5) LIMIT 15;"
```

You have to put AND and not && in there.

Comment: sorry, i highlighted this string as a code, but actuly it is printed array so it has the same view in the code

Comment: Updated with the correction to the SELECT statement

Comment: it doesn't work even with AND. But query is correct because, if i hard write the code, query is successefully handled

Comment: I had changed the description of the trouble, could u see it?